# Unable to access axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webforms, axios

I am trying to access the axios call from react component.

I tried to pass axios via resource and access it via this.axios but
error: this.axios.post is not a function

Question: 
How can i import the axios.js inside my react component. 
Is it possible to access axios.js from other javascript file.
I am not using any webpack here.

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ParentPage" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Session.aspx.cs" Inherits="SessionPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMiddlePanel" runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    let socketID = '<%=Session["userSocketID"] %>';
    let identityUserName = '<%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"\", @"\\") %>';
    </script>

    <!--React Script-->
    <script src="Scripts/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/react.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/react-dom.js"></script>

  <div class="Session">
      <div id="Session_React"></div>
  </div>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="includes/scripts/Session.js"></script>
  <script>
    let res = {
      makePing: makePing,
      axios: axios,
     };
    renderSharing(res);
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Session.js

```
type Props = {
  resources: any;
}

type state = {
  activeSessions : any;
  CurrentUserName: any;
}   

class SessionSharing extends React.Component<Props, state> {

  private makePing: any;
  private axios: any;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.makePing = res.makePing.bind(this);
    this.axios = res.axios.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      activeSessions: []
    };
  }

  getSession() {
    var path = "Session.aspx/GetSessions";
    this.axios
      .post(path, { withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => {
        let element = JSON.parse(response.data.d);

        this.setState({
          activeSessions: element
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderSessionDetails()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function renderSharing(res){
  ReactDOM.render(
  <Session resources={res}/>,
  document.getElementById('Session_React')
);  
}
```

Comment: `this.axios = res.axios.bind(this);` what is `res`? it doesn't need to be bound at all, just imported (like in the answer below)

Answer (score 1):

You should install axios with npm (yarn) and import it in your js file:

*npm install --save axios*

*import axios from 'axios'*

Then you can use function componentDidMount with axios inside for make request.
Also, don't bind axios, just import.

Answer (score 1):

added axios.js in my script folder 
and added this line of code in my typescript

```
import axios = require('../../Scripts/axios');
```